# Having trouble finding specific strings in a txt file

Tags: c

Here is the code I have:

```
int findKey(char *in, char *key, int buf){
int count = 0;
FILE *f;
f = fopen(in,"r");
char temp[buf];
while(fgets(temp,buf,f) != NULL){
    char *p = temp;
    while((p=(strstr(p,key)))!=NULL){
        count++;
        ++p;
    }
    int i = 0;
}
fclose(f);
return count;
}
```

So `char *in` is a txt file and key is the word I'm looking for in the txt file. So for example the txt file could be

```
hello Hello hello helloworld worldhello !hello! hello? hello, ?hello hello
```

and if the key word is "hello", then count should return 2. However in this case it is returning 9 because it is also counting these as valid:

```
helloworld worldhello !hello! hello? hello, ?hello
```

when it should only count the bolded as valid

**hello** Hello **hello** helloworld worldhello !hello! hello? hello, ?hello **hello**

How can I fix this?

Comment: You split the string on whitespace characters using `strtok_r()`, then check if each substring equals to `"hello"`.

Comment: `strtok_r` is a GNU Libc extension.

Comment: @randomusername It's not a GLibC extension, it's POSIX...

Comment: If `strtok_r` bothers you then just use `strtok`. Either way, that's the right direction to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This new routine works, and can be extended to support other types of delimiters besides `" \n\r\t"` (all the white space characters) easily.  Just be careful as it uses dynamic allocation but it is absolutely 100% portable.

```
int count = 0;
FILE *f = fopen (in, "r");
char *tmp = calloc (1, 1);
int len = 0;
while (! feof (f)) {
  tmp = realloc (tmp, len + buf);
  fgets (&tmp[len], buf, f);
  len += buf;
}
fclose (f);
strtok (tmp, "");
char *p;
while ((p = strtok (NULL, " \n\r\t")) != NULL)
  if (strcmp (p, key) == 0)
    count += 1;
free (tmp);
return count;
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to modify the input file, only to read from it.

Comment: Try this trick, it won't work at the very start of the buffer though.

Comment: That works but how I I make it work for also at the beginning of the txt file?

Comment: The very first time that you read the file, do `temp == strstr (temp, key)`

Comment: Okay I did that and it is able to find the first occurance of key. However if the input is something simple like `hello hello`. It cannot find the second hello. Also if the input is something like `hello hello\nhello1` Then it outputs 2(which is correct) but the the hello's it finds are not right. It finds the first 1 and then identifies hello1 as hello.

Comment: Okay, since you want such a generalized method, I'll edit my answer and write one for you that uses a different style.  Then try to reverse engineer what's going on so that you understand it.

Answer (score 0):

A `scanf()` solution:

Both test string and/or key are unchanged. (`const`).

```
void findKey(void) {
  const char *in =
          "hello Hello hello helloworld worldhello !hello! hello? hello, ?hello hello";
  const char *key = "hello";
  int count = 0;
  char temp[strlen(in) + 1];
  const char *p = in;
  while (*p) {
    int n;
    if (1 != sscanf(p, " %s%n", temp, &n)) {
      break;
    }
    if (0 == strcmp(key, temp)) {
      count++;
    }
  p = &p[n];
 }
printf("%d\n", count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using `memcmp()` and `isspace()`:

No temp buffer needed

```
unsigned findKey(const char *in, const char *key) {
  unsigned count = 0;
  size_t keyLen = strlen(key);
  int Ready = 1;
  while (*in) {
    while (isspace((unsigned char) *in)) { in++; Ready = 1; }
    if (Ready) {
      if (memcmp(in, key, keyLen) == 0 &&
          (isspace((unsigned char) in[keyLen]) || (in[keyLen] == '\0'))) {
        count++;
      }
      Ready = 0;
    }
    in++;
  }
  return count;
}
```